# Failed to Connect Issues with Okhttp3

Tags: okhttp, network-connection

I'm trying to run this simple java program that downloads a URL and print its content as a string. The full source is available at [OkHttpSourceCode](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/square/okhttp/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/guide/GetExample.java)

The error is below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:127)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:239)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:159)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:256)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:142)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
at GetExample.run(GetExample.java:17)
at GetExample.main(GetExample.java:24)
```

Although the error says the connection timed out, there is no issue with the connection. I am running this on Eclipse behind a corporate proxy and can access internal websites without any issues.I've configured cntlm proxy and it works without any issues. I can access marketplace as well so there cannot be any issues with the network configurations.

The eclipse network setting is set at 'Native' that includes localhost:port if that helps. Any help is greatly appreciated in resolving this issue.